# Why `x += a + d[x]` works fine but `x +=a; x += d[x]` fails?

Tags: python, refactoring

I was recently refactoring this snippet and I broke it:

```
            if from_mac in self.announces:                                     
                from_mac += '\\nAnnounces: ' + ',\\n'.join(self.announces[from_mac])
            if to_mac in self.announces:                                       
                to_mac += '\\nAnnounces: ' + ',\\n'.join(self.announces[to_mac])
```

After my refactoring, it looked like this to make the lines shorter:

```
            if from_mac in self.announces:                                     
                from_mac += '\\nAnnounces: '
                from_mac += ',\\n'.join(self.announces[from_mac])
            if to_mac in self.announces:                                       
                to_mac += '\\nAnnounces: '
                to_mac += ',\\n'.join(self.announces[to_mac])
```

The types for variables are:

```
to_mac, from_mac -> string
self.announces = defaultdict(list)  # of strings
```

The unwanted effect of this refactorization is that I am getting strings like this:

```
"\nAnnounces: \nAnnounces: \nAnnounces: "
```

What could be the cause of that?

## Context

Here's the whole function and its output:

```
def print_report(self, skip_broadcast=False):                                  
    """                                                                        
    Prints out a DOT file based on the gathered information.                   
    """                                                                        
    sys.stderr.write("%s\n" % repr(self.announces))                            
    print("strict digraph {")                                                  
    for from_mac in self.seen:                                                 
        sys.stderr.write("k1=%s\n" % from_mac)                                 
        for to_mac in self.seen[from_mac]:                                     
            sys.stderr.write("k2=%s\n" % to_mac)                               
            if skip_broadcast and (from_mac == '?' or to_mac == '?'):          
                continue                                                       
            if from_mac in self.announces:                                     
                from_mac += '\\nAnnounces: '                                   
                from_mac += ',\\n'.join(self.announces[from_mac])              
            if to_mac in self.announces:                                       
                to_mac += '\\nAnnounces: '                                     
                to_mac += ',\\n'.join(self.announces[to_mac])                  
            print('"%s" -> "%s";' % (from_mac, to_mac))                        
    print("}")
```

And the output:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'Cisco-Li_99:13:54\\n(58:6d:8f:99:13:54)': ['FajnaSiec']})
strict digraph {
k1=Cisco-Li_99:13:54\n(58:6d:8f:99:13:54)
k2=IPv6mcast_01\n(33:33:00:00:00:01)
"Cisco-Li_99:13:54\n(58:6d:8f:99:13:54)\nAnnounces: " -> "IPv6mcast_01\n(33:33:00:00:00:01)";
k2=IPv4mcast_01\n(01:00:5e:00:00:01)
"Cisco-Li_99:13:54\n(58:6d:8f:99:13:54)\nAnnounces: \nAnnounces: " -> "IPv4mcast_01\n(01:00:5e:00:00:01)";
k2=Tp-LinkT_20:74:8b\n(e8:94:f6:20:74:8b)
"Cisco-Li_99:13:54\n(58:6d:8f:99:13:54)\nAnnounces: \nAnnounces: \nAnnounces: " -> "Tp-LinkT_20:74:8b\n(e8:94:f6:20:74:8b)";
k2=?
"Cisco-Li_99:13:54\n(58:6d:8f:99:13:54)\nAnnounces: \nAnnounces: \nAnnounces: \nAnnounces: " -> "?";
k1=SamsungE_05:50:0e\n(00:e3:b2:05:50:0e)
k2=Cisco-Li_99:13:54\n(58:6d:8f:99:13:54)
"SamsungE_05:50:0e\n(00:e3:b2:05:50:0e)" -> "Cisco-Li_99:13:54\n(58:6d:8f:99:13:54)\nAnnounces: ";
k1=?
k2=Cisco-Li_99:13:54\n(58:6d:8f:99:13:54)
"?" -> "Cisco-Li_99:13:54\n(58:6d:8f:99:13:54)\nAnnounces: ";
k2=SamsungE_05:50:0e\n(00:e3:b2:05:50:0e)
"?" -> "SamsungE_05:50:0e\n(00:e3:b2:05:50:0e)";
k2=?
"?" -> "?";
}
```

Comment: In your refactored example, the value of `from_mac` in the right hand expression is *different* than it is in your original code. In other words, it's not just a simple case of `x += a + b` but here `b` depends upon the value of `x`. So `x += a + f(x)` is *not* the same as `x += a` followed by `x += f(x)` since the value of `x` in the second case is *different*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user `lurker` said in his comment, this is because the first expression changes what `from_mac` is and then the lookup in the dictionary fails. A solution would be to introduce a new variable that would be used for displaying only.